# Iterate a select statement in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have prepared a select statement.

```
sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT symbol,image FROM test WHERE template=? AND field=?", -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, pParams->pszFile, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 2, pParams->pszFieldId, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

How to go about iterating through the results?

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this document](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT symbol,image FROM test WHERE template=? AND field=?", -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, pParams->pszFile, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 2, pParams->pszFieldId, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);  

 if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  int ncols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);

  while(rc == SQLITE_ROW)
  {

      for(i=0; i < ncols; i++)
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "'%s' ", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i));
      }

      fprintf(stderr, "\n");
      rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  }

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`sqlite3_step()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) function for this purpose.

Comment: How do I get the results? I.e. how do I read the actual data after sqlite_step()? Also, how do I know when to stop reading?

Comment: @sashoalm Read the manual for which I provided a link. Search for "column access functions" in the text.